# Forced re-entry of all man-made satellites in short moment notice

Tags: science-based, technology, apocalypse, space-constructs

Is it possible to manipulate all artificial satellites(including [ISS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Space_Station)) and space junks currently in orbit to fall into Earth's atmosphere in one go? (Tech level is late 22nd century science)

Note: I need a plot for my villain to threaten the world.

Comment: What's the time frame for deorbiting all the satellites? How large are the satellites? If they aren't above a certain size, deorbiting them all won't matter one iota.

Comment: @Green how about making all man-made objects crewed or not to decelerate at once so that they fall towards Earth. I don't need all of them to impact Earth simultaneously but they must decelerate at the same time on command.

Comment: No one worries about satellites crashing into earth because below a certain size, they just burn up in the atmosphere. You can see this happen in a meteor shower. Have a look at Kessler Syndrome if you want something really scary. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kessler_syndrome

Comment: @Green do you mean that none of the falling satellites can leave marks on Earth's surface? in that case at least I can still disable the intercontinental communication as a backup plot.

Comment: That's correct. If you could crash something the size of Ceres into earth, that would be a very large threat.

Comment: If you needed to deorbit all satellites for some other reason than a villian's threat, this is a very interesting question. But as a threat of destruction, it's not credible.

Comment: Does this include satellites in geostationary orbit?  At L1 and L2?  Heliocentric orbit??

Comment: @2012rcampion  I imagine those would fall under *"**All** artificial satellites and space junks currently in orbit"*?

Comment: @Double But it's not clear if (s)he means just *Earth* orbit (do we need to pull [Cassini](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cassini%E2%80%93Huygens) back from Saturn?), or whether (s)he considers satellites like [Triana](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deep_Space_Climate_Observatory), [SOHO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solar_and_Heliospheric_Observatory), or [JWST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/James_Webb_Space_Telescope) (when it launches) to be in Earth orbit.  (If (s)he's just targeting comms satellites, then my guess is we could ignore everything outside of GEO.)

Comment: I believe that just disabling them would be catastrophic enough.

Comment: if the bad guy could do that, he'd run the world without need for threats.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not really, unless there is an unexpected breakthrough. [Space debris](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_debris) is a problem for exactly that reason. The only force which affects *all* objects is gravity and we can't manipulate that.

- Perhaps a big flyswatter/net on a [retrograde orbit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Retrograde_and_prograde_motion). It would have to be big, but also strong enough to survive the impact of sats coming the other way.
- A large number of smaller, maneuvering orbital tugs. But you would need a real lot of them to get the junk as well.

Comment: Note that your net would need to be able to 1) be massive enough to absorb the momentum of tens of thousands of objects without immediately deorbiting itself, 2) be able to withstand collisions at 14-15 km/s without puncturing or spalling, and 3) be at least 5.6 Re (Earth radii) long to capture sats in both GEO and LEO at once.

Comment: @2012rcampion - Shrug. "late 22nd century science." And you'd just make a whole potload of them which would take up station near their designated targets, waiting for the "go" signal, at which point they would dock and deorbit. The latter is very nearly doable today, so 150 years of technological advancement would seem to be up to the job. Getting a usable delta-v in a small enough package would be the big problem. Project Orion, anyone?

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast, Orion tends to be big craft. Steam rockets heated by lasers from geostationary stations? Solar-powered ion engines?

Answer (score 1):

You could probably de-orbit a bunch of stuff by:

Hacking into mission control for a bunch of major satellite players: all satellites require periodic burns to maintain orbit until their end of life, when they are put into a grave-yard orbit or sent to burn up in the atmosphere.  If you got your mitts on the controls for a satellite, you could alter its orbit enough that it would eventually enter atmosphere.  How long it would take is a function of how much fuel is available.

Building some "laser-brooms": use a high power laser to ablate the surface of satellites - generating thrust.  If you put several brooms in orbit, you could likely change the path of a large number of satellites pretty rapidly.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laser_broom

That being said, the atmosphere does a good job of protecting us from space debris.  Your evil villain would succeed in disrupting GPS, satellite comms, etc, but basically nothing would impact the surface of the earth.  It would inconvenience a lot of people and physically harm basically no-one.

If you've got the ability to hack into government satellite controls and/or launch your own satellites, just build your own "rods-from-God" and call it a day.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kinetic_bombardment

Comment: Maintaining a highly specific orbit and staying in orbit however are two quite different things. GEO satellites require fairly precise station-keeping, for example, not really to remain in GEO (they likely would for decades at least without deliberate station-keeping) but rather to remain *in their specific assigned GEO orbital slot*. Only in quite low Earth orbit (up to perhaps 500 km or so) is drag enough of a concern that you can deorbit much of anything in a reasonable time frame simply by preventing station-keeping.

Comment: I'm saying use fuel intended for station keeping to Detroit.

Comment: My phone auto corrected de orbit as a city name...

Answer (score 0):

"One go" is pretty vague.  Does this mean over the course of an hour, day, month, year?  Does it mean that the event that causes them to fall affects all of them, but once it occurs they may fall out of orbit depending on their size, speed, orbital parameters, etc?

Satellites are in "orbit" merely because they are traveling quickly.  Slow them down and they "fall".

The only way that might work is if the Earth was sideswiped by a huge meteor shower.  Aimed well enough, it would wipe out the vast majority of satellites without destroying the planet itself.  It would also remove a good chunk of the upper atmosphere as well, but you can't make omelettes without breaking a few eggs.

Answer (score 0):

If you'll accept simply taking them out of orbit, not necessarily re-entry:

Two degenerate masses fly by the Earth, close enough to cause nasty tides but far enough out that Earth stays well clear of their Roche limit.  The approach speed is low so they spend a fair amount of time near Earth.  Normally this would cause some nasty orbital effects but the two masses counterbalance almost perfectly (a perfect match is impossible as it means they would impact each other post-encounter.)

If the masses are heavy enough I don't think anything could remain in orbit but whether it re-entered or was ejected is another matter.

Comment: If the approach speed is low, the thing will fall out of the sky and hit earth.

Comment: @Oldcat If it's coming from infinity it will pick up enough speed during the flyby to head back out so long as it's not on an impact path.